# Analyticity of unramifed part of Rankin-Selberg $L$-functions on $\Re(s)=1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

I have only a little knowledge about automorphic representations and $L$-functions. Now I am reading the textbook of Goldfeld and Hundley on automorphic representations, and also planning to read the textbook of Cogdell, Kim, and Murty, Lectures on Automorphic $L$-functions. I only have some basic knowledge in classical settings (i.e., $L$-functions of Hecke eigenforms of $GL(2)$).

The reason why I try to read these is the following question.

Let $f$ and $g$ be Hecke eigenforms of weight $2$, level $N$, where $N$ is a squarefree positive integer.

As in the introduction of Cogdell and Michel's paper 2004, 'On the complex moments of symmetric power $L$-functions at $s=1$' for instance, the $r$-th symmetric power of $f$ or $g$ exist if $r=1,2,3,4$. In other words, as I understand, there is a cuspidal automorphic representation (at least I know the definition of some basic stuff, e.g., automorphic and cuspidal automorphic representations of $GL(n,\mathbb A)$), say $\pi$ and $\pi'$, respectively, of which $L$-functions are the same as the $r_1$ and $r_2$-th symmetric power $L$-function $L(s,f,\mathrm{Sym}^{r_1})$ and $L(s,g,\mathrm{Sym}^{r_2})$, respectively ($r_1,r_2 \in \{1,2,3,4\}$).

Therefore, one can consider the Rankin-Selberg $L$-function $L(s,\pi \times \pi')$. I heard that this $L$-function is entire (more precisely, has the analytic continuation that is entire) except for some special cases (for example, $\pi \simeq \pi'$). In particular, it is holomorphic at $s=1$.

In fact, it is referred to in p. 225 of Cogdell-Kim-Murty that the completed $L$-function of $L(s,\pi \times \pi')$ is entire except at $s=1-it$, which is a pole when $\pi \simeq \pi' \otimes |\mathrm{det}|^{it}$. Hereafter we assume $\pi \not\simeq \pi' \otimes |\mathrm{det}|^{it}$.

I should mention at this point that I don't know what $|\mathrm{det}|$ is and also don't know the exact definition of $L$-functions of automorphic representations.

Therefore, I am not sure that the above entirety of the completed $L$-function implies the entirety of $L(s,\pi \times \pi')$, but I guess that is so (because it seems that the completed $L$-function has the extra 'archimedean factor' and at least in the classical setting, this is non-zero holomorphic at $s=1$. If this is not true, please let me know.)

On the other hand, Theorem 5.2 of Shahidi's 1981 paper, 'On certain $L$-functions', says that if $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are irreducible admissible cuspidal representations, then then the unramified part of $L(s,\pi \times \pi')$, namely

$$
L_S(s,\pi \times \pi')=\prod_{v \not\in S}L(s,\pi_v \times \pi_v')
$$

is non-zero at any $s=1+it, t\in \mathbb R$. In particular, this statement holds for our $\pi$ and $\pi'$.

Here is what I wonder. Shahidi's result is about the unramified part of $L$-function. Also, it does not state that $L_S(s,\pi \times \pi')$ is holomorphic at $s=1+it$, even though we already know that the completed $L$-function of $L(s,\pi \times \pi')$ is holomorphic at $s=1+it$. Thus I would like to know whether $L_S(s,\pi \times \pi')$ is also holomorphic on $\Re(s)=1$, or similarly, whether $L(s,\pi \times \pi')$ is non-zero on $\Re(s)=1$.

In other words, I wonder whether the ramified part of $L(s,\pi \times \pi')$ does not affect the order of points on $\Re(s)=1$ (and want to know that the archimedean part also doesn't affect).

As I said, although all of these contexts exist, I don't know the precise definition of the automorphic $L$-function. Thus, I am trying to get basic stuff using the textbooks I mentioned, but as you know, it takes a long time to get some preliminaries. Therefore, I would like to know the 'fact' first, namely, whether these guesses are really true.

In short,

> Question. Let $\pi$ and $\pi'$ be irreducible admissible cuspidal representations of $GL(r_1,\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$ and $GL(r_2, \mathbb A_{\mathbb Q})$, respectively, for which $\pi$ is not isomorphic to any of $\pi' \otimes |\mathrm{det}|^{it}$ for $t \in \mathbb R$. Is the 'unramified part' of $L(s,\pi \times \pi')$,
> $$
> \prod_{v \not\in S} L(s,\pi_v \times \pi_v')
> $$
> is holomorphic on a line $\Re(s)=1$?

Thank you for reading and I appreciate it if you already know about these facts and let me know.

Comment: I'd encourage you to make your question more concise, and try to ask a single, well-formed question.  (I think you can get your question down to 1 paragraph, maybe 2.)

Comment: Kimball // Thank you for the reasonable advice. I added a short, single summary of the question.